# How can I open .bash_profile without a command-line editor?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, hidden-files

I am able to get to and edit my `.bash_profile`, but only using nano which lacks features I would like. How can I edit my `.bash_profile` in an external app, such as vscode?

I am using Windows 10 and it won't show up in search or when I check "Hidden items" in my home directory in explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this in the terminal "code .bash_profile" to open it in the vscode, "pluma .bash_profile" to open it with pluma etc

or you could ctrl+h to view hidden files then in the file manager, [right click or is it left click] choose open with and then open it with a different program of your choice.